# Can i change index id or sort data in JSON data Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to sort my data by date, like this: 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018. With index 0, 1, 2, 3 that is my first data. For the second set of data I just have 2017, at index 0.

I want 2017 in index 2, or I push null data but 2017 still in index 0. anybody know for solution?

I tried with javascript code:

```
for (let index = 0; index < baseyear.length; index++) {
    const element = baseyear[index];
    if (element[0].tahun !== '2015') {
       element.push(
                   {"tahun":null,"lokasi":null,"Jumlahproduksi":null},
                   {"tahun":null,"lokasi":null,"Jumlahproduksi":null},
                   {"tahun":null,"lokasi":null,"Jumlahproduksi":null}
                   );
     } 
     console.log(element);                 
}
```

for more explain see this picture:
[image: data ilustration]

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: If you are sorting data by date  and you want to 2017 to be at index 2 then you need to add 2 values which have lesser date than 2017. May be you can try pushing 2015, 2016 as tahun and other properties as null.

Comment: not sure why you are pushing null values with 3 objects any specific condition